# when to close the php tags so it doesnt intefere with the html

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to apply a dropdown menu which pulls usernames from my database.
I have the code for it below.

```
<?php  

$host="******"; // Host name
$username="******"; // Mysql username
$password="*****"; // Mysql password
$db_name="*******"; // Database name

$cn=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name,$cn) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT usernameSchool FROM schools";
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo ?>"<select>";
  <?php  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
echo ?>"  <option value= <?php'".$row["usernameSchools"]."'?> >".$row["userameSchool"]."</option>";
}mysql_free_result($rs);
echo "</select>";

?>
```

When i try to load the page some of the php scripts start to show when i have the php open and closing tags at the start and the finish.

I tried to put some in the middle of the code when i switched from html to php however this is now resulting in other issues such as the information from the database not coming through as well as random quotation marks.
Im not sure where my syntax has gone wrong.

If anyone could tell me when to open and close these tags it would be really helpful.

The page this data is on is a mix of html and php at the moment.

Comment: What is showing when you just include everything in a single set of tags?

Answer (score 1):

This is ludicrously UGLY code:

```
echo ?>"<select>";
  <?php
```

Why not simply have

```
echo "<select>";
```

and be done with it? There is NO need to jump in/out of PHP mode the way you are. You're simply making the code extremely DIFFICULT to follow.

Answer (score 0):

But it's so much prettier with [alternative syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) :D

```
<?php  

$host="******"; // Host name
$username="******"; // Mysql username
$password="*****"; // Mysql password
$db_name="*******"; // Database name

$cn=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name,$cn) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT usernameSchool FROM schools";
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<select>

<?php  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)):?>
        <option value='<?php echo $row["usernameSchools"];?>'>
             <?php echo $row["userameSchool"];?>
        </option>
<?php  endwhile;
      mysql_free_result($rs);
?>

</select>
```

Also, **PLEASE STOP USING THE `mysql_` extension for new code!!!!!*** Use MySQLi or PDO instead as the mysql_ extension is now deprecated and insecure.